# Contact Form 7 вывод вместе c title

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Как отобразить шорткод вместе с названием формы из админки (post_title) ?

Comment: Где "отобразить"?

Comment: на сайте, в любом месте на фронте

Comment: А прописать нужный текст (название в твоём случае) прямо в конструкторе формы - фантазии не хватает?

Comment: Ух фантазер, это самое простое что можно сделать. По верстке не походит. Есть что по теме, ответить, слушаю

Comment: Учи css и тогда "по вёрстке" всё подойдёт.